# How to add rows in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data as in this BigQuery table

```
+-------+---------+------+------+
| chrom |  start  | stop | cons |
+-------+---------+------+------+
| chr1  | 1       | 5    | 0.3  |
| chr1  | 5       | 7    | 0.7  |
| chr2  | 1       | 3    | 0.2  |
+-------+---------+------+------+
```

where the value in "cons" is true for every number from start to stop (though the number in stop itself is excluded). Now I'd like to have the data in an non aggregated way, so the table would look like this

```
+-------+---------+------+------+
| chrom |  start  | stop | cons |
+-------+---------+------+------+
| chr1  | 1       | 2    | 0.3  |
| chr1  | 2       | 3    | 0.3  |
| chr1  | 3       | 4    | 0.3  |
| chr1  | 4       | 5    | 0.3  |
| chr1  | 5       | 6    | 0.7  |
| chr1  | 6       | 7    | 0.7  |
| chr2  | 1       | 2    | 0.2  |
| chr2  | 2       | 3    | 0.2  |
+-------+---------+------+------+
```

The

```
INSERT INTO
```

command is not supported by BigQuery. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: BigQuery now supports SQL INSERT. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an aid table called "Numbers" and contains integer numbers from 0 - to largest reasonable value
2. Cross Join your table with the Numbers table
3. in the where close enforce Numbers.Number>=Start and Number.Number

It should look something like:

```
Select chrome, Numbers.Number as Start, Numbers.Number+1 as stop, cons
from yourtable
cross join Numbers
where Numbers.Number>=Start and Number.Number<stop
```

4. Save your results to a new table or override the existing one.

Hope this helps

Comment: I also thought about this solution. However, I'd need an aid table with ~150.000.000 rows - which I hoped to avoid.

Comment: You can check using a 1000 rows numbers table and doing this cross join 3 times... If you do, please share your results.

Comment: The CROSS JOIN works fine, I changed the code to something like this
/br
Select my.chrom, numbers.chrom, numbers.number AS Start, numbers.number+1 AS Stop, my.cons
from mytable AS my
cross join aidtable AS numbers
where my.chrom = numbers.chrom AND
      numbers.number >= start AND numbers.number < stop

Why would I do the CROSS JOIN 3 times?

Comment: You were concerned about the size of the aid table that will result in huge cross join,  e.g. 1000000 records in your table, with 150000000 aid records will result in 150000000000000 cross join records. If you iterate 3 times through a smaller 1000 records table, you'll have much smaller cross join results.

Comment: Actually my resulting table is 1000 rows long, exactly as aid table. There is no multiplication of the entries. I guess I have to use a 150.000.000 row aid table, it's after all the fastest....